# QGIS 3D Globe Plugin Elevation Map Projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, globe

I'm trying to get a map setup using the QGIS 'Globe Plugin'. I've been trying to use the UK Environment Agency LIDAR data as an elevation map. After a bit of puzzling this out I've found that the Elevation Map needs to be in WGS 84 projection.

Is it just the case that you need to reproject the elevation map to be WGS 84 before using it, or is there a way to use other projections?

I hope that explanation isn't too confusing, but let me know if you need clarification on anything.